# Connect SEGA Mega Drive 2 to smart TV

Tags: sega-genesis

I have an old console, SEGA Mega Drive 2:
[image: SEGA Mega Drive 2]

The outputs:
[image]

How can I connect to my LG 55UH605V television?
[image]

Which type of cable/converter do need I to buy, for the best experience?

Comment: I know I'm being a bit picky here, but that your TV is a "smart" TV is irrelevant to the question. The "smart" label is just a marketing term usually to indicate it has Internet functionality.

Comment: Nobody is going to say anything about the framemeister? Input lag?

Comment: @LateralTerminal you should be that person! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I would connect it in this way. The Video output of SEGA Mega Drive 2 would be connected to the **Video(Y)** at the back of the TV and the audio out of Sega would connect to White **Audio/Mono** socket at the back of the TV.

A simple dual-RCA cable would suffice in this scenario. The console outputs a mono channel sound-stream, and your TV has provision to accept exactly that.

> [image: RCA Cable]

Comment: This is the correct answer. The green/yellow port is even labeled `VIDEO / Y` and the white port is labeled `L / MONO`. Since the Mega Drive 2 has composite video out and mono audio out, the "video" output goes to the "video" input, and the "audio" output goes to the "mono" input. The labeling on the TV explicitly (if not clearly) indicates that it understands composite video and mono audio.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I ordered yesterday a 3-3 RCA cabel. It will not work?

Comment: @user594297 it will work perfectly, you will just have one unused connector hanging at each side

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the back of your TV, I don't see why you can't just use normal [RCA cables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RCA_connector). The yellow cable (video) would plug into the yellow/green socket, and the red one (audio) into one of those red sockets (not sure which).   Alternatively, you could get an [RCA to HDMI](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6PF5745652&cm_re=rca_to_hdmi-_-9SIA6PF5745652-_-Product) converter like the one below.  This would require a separate HDMI cable, and an RCA cable.  You will also have to power the unit externally.  This one is powered via USB.

[image: converter]

Experience wise - I don't think you'll gain much benefit by using one of these methods over the other. Maybe a bit cleaner of an image via the HDMI connector, but I'm not sure how the converting scales.

**Edit:**

I can't tell for sure, but some sites and [videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vewyua88R3M) seem to suggest that you need to use the RF Wire port seen on the back of your console, and an RF Unit supplied with the console like [this one](http://www.sorethumbretrogames.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/s/e/sega_megadrive_rf_unit.jpeg).  This unit would then connect up to the antenna socket on your television, which your television does have (next to the Cable In socket). I'm not too familiar with this console, but I can't imagine the RCA connections not working for this since that is how RCA cables work (at least that's how it worked for my old Sega Saturn).

Side note - looking around at images of the Mega Drive 2, none of them appear to have RCA connections at all... which confuses me as to why yours *does*.

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. The yellow would go into the yellow on the system and the yellow/green on the TV for video. I think the red would go into the red on the system and maybe the white (mono) on the TV for audio - though it could be the red Audio.

What really confused me, however, was the "RF Wire - TV" slot

Comment: Thanks the quick help! ;)
So I need an RCA cabel, like this?
https://www.ebay.com/itm/3-RCA-Stecker-auf-3-Cinch-Stecker-Composite-Audio-Video-AV-Kabel-Stecker-1M/282696054976?hash=item41d1ff78c0:g:TfoAAOSwuMZZJ7aI

Comment: @user594297 they should yes.  But see my edit.  Where did you get the console? Is it a legitimate one made by Sega?

Comment: It is hard to find any real descriptions of the Mega Drive 2 [especially as it compares to Genesis 2], but it looks like maybe you can use component AV or RF cable.

Comment: This is not a real Sega, this is a popular scam console..
I think I don't need the RF Unit, I try the RCA cabel.
Thanks! ;)

Comment: I'm confused by this sentence: "the antenna socket on your television, which your television does not have"; the image shows *two* coaxial sockets, one labelled "antenna in", and the other "cable in".

Comment: @IMSoP I missed that.  I edited my post.

Comment: That "RCA to HDMI" cable is almost certainly either a special-purpose adapter or fake. HDMI cannot transmit analog audio/video signals, and a converter would generally require external power.

Comment: @duskwuff the [amazon page](https://www.amazon.com/Auskic-Component-Converter-Adapter-Projectors/dp/B01FSH0M3O) I pulled this from states "No chipset to convert digital signals to analogy signals, just fits for devices with chip which can convert digital signals to analogy signals" so it's not a good example.  I'll update my post with a proper one.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see from the picture, your first RCA connector is half green and half yellow, this means that it can accept both Green component either Composite video.

Most of the AV devices uses to accept mono audio on the left channel input.

Said so you can just connect Mega Drive Yellow to the Yellow/Green RCA and the Red one to the white one using an RCA Male/Male cable.

Answer (score 1):

Just bought a megadrive 2 to resell and tested it using Red wHite Yellow cable RCA to AV cable. Sound works fine but black and white graphics. When using the original RCA cable that has the ANT RF switch sound is white noise and the graphics are great and in colour.

Answer (score -1):

i have one of the sega genesis consoles and i have been told apparently there is a cable called an av to rca cable it has 9 pin connection one end that plugs into the same port the old rf unit plugged into and the other end has the yellow and red and white audio and visual plugs. There are several listed on trade me now under sega megadrive av audio video tv cable for bout 5 bucks plus shipping. I'm just trying to find a console repair shop that sells them also cause its easier for me to go into. Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you actually answering the question, and if so, could you tell *how* this is helpful?